# how to rename pyramind of numbers file

Tags: bash

I have 1000+ files on my Linux machine:

```
somefiletest001.DAT_999
somefiletest001.DAT_1000
somefiletest001.DAT_1000_1001
somefiletest001.DAT_1000_1001_1002
somefiletest001.DAT_1000_1001_1002_1003
```

I would like to know how to rename them to:

```
somefiletest001.DAT_999
somefiletest001.DAT_1000
somefiletest001.DAT_1001
somefiletest001.DAT_1002
somefiletest001.DAT_1003
```

I can do mv command one by one at the time. Can someone show me how to do a simple bash script to rename this kind of files? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: How is that possible?  Would you not have exceeded the max filename length?  Filename 1000 would be over 5000 chars long.

Comment: @Inian - I'm no Linux person, I'm just want to make my life simpler. Doing `mv somefilenametest001.DAT_1000_1002_1003 somefilenametest001.DAT_1003` command every each files will take times, I can just put them into a file, pasting every each files then run it later. Hope understand what I'm saying and what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **`prename`** (***Perl*** rename) command:

```
prename 's/\.DAT(_.*)?(_[0-9]{4})$/.DAT$2/' *.DAT_*
```

Comment: Thank you! @RomanPerekhrest. It work like a charm. I have to do `man prename` to know what I'm doing. Thank you again for a quick help.